# Improve quality of video recording in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, video, microsoft-powerpoint, screen-capture, video-codecs

When I capture the video with Win key + G, the quality of the video is awful. To give you a rough idea about the awfulness of quality, here is a screenshot of the original image vs capture one:

[image: 1]

I changed Win10 settings according to the following link but the result is hopeless:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026653/windows-10-video-quality-of-game-clips

I also tried to [capture the screen using the MS Powerpoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/record-your-screen-in-powerpoint-0b4c3f65-534c-4cf1-9c59-402b6e9d79d0), but the result is the same.

Comment: why leave a negative vote without any comment? what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Note that a lower frame rate may give better appearance when (frame rate) * (image appearance) is fixed.

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but note that some users are reluctant to add an accompanying comment because of [things like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353978/1115360).

Answer (score 2):

If you have in *Settings > Gaming > Captures* set under "Recorded video" the
frame rate to "60 fps" and "Video quality" to High, then you have done all that's
possible with the Windows Settings app.

If that's not enough, you might have more luck with registry settings.
I suggest to at least create a System Restore point before doing registry work,
to be able to undo them in case of problem.
Reboot before testing new registry settings.

The registry settings are under the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR`.
They are documented by Microsoft under the page
[Windows.Media.Capture Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture?view=winrt-19041).

The useful ones are:

- `VideoEncodingBitrateMode` : The value `1` stands for High bitrate.
- `VideoEncodingFrameRateMode` : The value `1` stands for high frame rate.
- `VideoEncodingResolutionMode` : The value `0` stands for Custom.
  The resolution is then specified by `CustomVideoEncodingHeight` and `CustomVideoEncodingBitrate`.
- `CustomVideoEncodingHeight` : Custom video encoding height
- `CustomVideoEncodingBitrate` : Custom video encoding bitrate of the broadcast stream
  in bits per second

If improving the above values does not improve the video quality, you might look
into alternate software. Have a look at
[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/),
but there are more to be found in many articles, for example in
[12 Best Game Recording Software for Windows](https://beebom.com/best-game-recording-software/).

Comment: thank you for the answer and effort. I checked settings > Gaming > Captures and the settings was as you suggested: 60 fps and high quality of video capture. I also checked the registry key and both VideoEncodingBitrateMode and VideoEncodingFrameRateMode are set to 1. I did not want to mess with the rest of the registry ... at the end of the day it was not fixed, however I applied a widget reset and after a reboot it seems working. If the situation remain stable, I will send it as an answer.

Comment: after few hours, without changing any settings, the problem is returned :-(

Comment: What means a widget reset?

Comment: look at this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMcYf.png

Comment: Which application is showing this window?

Comment: it is a windows builtin application. after pressing Winkey+ G it appears at the top of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Since PowerPoint is bad too, I'd recommend trying ffmpeg to record the screen.

See the "Windows" section of https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Windows

Separately try both the `gdigrab` and the `dshow` examples they show on that page in case one works better than the other.  I'd try `gdigrab` first though because it doesn't require anything additional to be installed.

Also see the hardware encoding section on that page for how to accelerate the encoding using an NVIDIA card (or if using an Intel CPU but no NVIDIA GPU you can use `h264_qsv` instead of `h264_nvenc` for hardware acceleration).

In the commands it lists, you can use `-b:v 5M` to set the video bitrate to 5Mbps which should be a decent test.

So for example this works for me for sharp fluid video at 1920x1080 (trying at 4K was too choppy) `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop  -b:v 5M  -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast test.mp4`

Comment: very good to know. actually it is not the answer to the question, however, it is a good way to capture the string without installing any application. because of that, I upvoted your answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Nvidia Shadowplay, AMD Relive, and OBS.

They are free, no watermark, almost no frame drops. And most importantly, Relive and Shadowplay can easily handle screen recording even you are running resource-intensive programs like playing WOW games.

Take a look, here's a 14 recording software-recommendation test review:
https://www.videoproc.com/download-record-video/game-screen-recorder.htm

Answer (score 0):

For free screen recording software I can only recommend [obs](https://obsproject.com/).

It is great, [open-source](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) software that can be used to screencapture or stream. It takes a little to get into, with adding sources and stuff, but for how powerful it is, it is actually very user friendly and is highly performant as well!