# Using Windows Game Bar to record in the background, how can I reduce the file size?

Tags: windows-10, video, gaming, recording

I use Windows Game Bar to record in the background sometimes. I am fine with the small drop in performance. I set the settings to Standard Resolution and 3 minute recordings. However, when I save the video, the file sizes are extremely large.

For a 3 minute video, the file size is 266MB. Is there a way I can reduce this for ALL recordings, somewhere in the settings? I don't mean reducing it after I save the recording, I want it to record all videos already reduced.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/video-quality-of-game-clips-in-windows-10-af8440c6-dd69-65fc-9e6d-c9872902862e

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the quality of the video, not adding audio, both work to reduce the file size.
Videos are large. Very large. They take up a lot of space unnecessarily, and it kind of angers people. I would recommend using something else for screen capturing like an OBS, and saving the file as a different, more optimized format of the file extension. In my experience, the Game Bar doesn't work to well, while recording from an OBS just takes less time.

Comment: This is mostly correct, though I contest the use of "unnecessarily". Videos necessarily require a lot of storage space, because there's a lot of visual data that needs storing. You may think, "but a JPEG screenshot only needs 0.5 megabytes". Yeah, now imagine having 30 of those per second. A naïve JPEG stream could need 15 MiB per second.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the file size, you must reduce the encoding quality or dimensions. Beyond using Standard quality and 30 FPS, your only choice will be to adjust registry settings to use a custom bitrate and/or dimensions. This answer contains details: https://superuser.com/a/1551671/457818

It's written from the perspective of increasing video quality, but you can use lower numbers, too. Unfortunately, there's no documentation that I can find about what values are valid for CustomVideoEncodingBitrate. You will just have to experiment.